# So, I have a confusion in using from or at

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say, I completed my intermediate studies at XYZ school in 2022 or I completed my intermediate studies from XYZ school in 2022?
I am confused in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **complete your studies at** a university (**in** a field) (**in** a year):

> *This past fall, she completed her studies at the University of Houston and will take part in commencement ceremonies in the spring.* (from [this page](https://uh.edu/af/news/archive/January2014/studentspot.htm))

You **study (something) at** a university:

> *My brother studied photography at the Royal College of Art.* (Oxford Dictionary)

You **get/have a degree from** a university:

> *My brother has a master's degree from Harvard.* (Oxford Dictionary)

Comment: OP asked about the phrase **completed my intermediate studies.** The connection between your examples and that exact phrase might not be obvious to an English language learner. Please add some clarification.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney. I have now added a section at the beginning to directly address the point raised in the question by OP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I am free of the confusion, now.